# RecyclerView - Animation for changes in Margin for instead of programmatically changing them

Tags: android

I have a recyclerView that starts off with a marginTop of 150dp. As I scroll up on the recyclerView, I want the marginTop to reduce until it reaches to 0 and takes up the whole screen, and the reverse when scrolling down back to 150dp marginTop.

Currently I am achieving this with the following

```
final RecyclerView v = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
//calculate px given the 150dp
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
final int px =  (int)((150 * displayMetrics.density) + 0.5);

v.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
                offset += dy;
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                lp.setMargins(0, px - offset, 0, 0);
                v.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });
```

This works fine, but often times it is not very smooth and feels very "jagged". Are there any better and smoother ways to implement this function, probably with some type of animation?

EDIT: I've posted a solution with potential solution for some people, but it is not what I'm looking for exactly. Please see comment for follow up question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167073/recyclerview-itemdecoration-blocks-touch-access-to-viewpager-behind-it

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential solution.

Create the following class

```
class PaddingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int size;

    PaddingItemDecoration(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0 ) {
            outRect.top += size;
        }
    }
}
```

and you can set it on your `recyclerView` like so

```
recyclePosts.addItemDecoration(new PaddingItemDecoration((int)size);
```

However, note that this will disable any on screen touch event that you may have behind this "invisible" padding of height `size`, rendering them untouchable.